# PHP How to group json object

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to ask about json object

i have json object like this:

```
{"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC01","TASK_NAME":"Human service 1"}
{"ID":"MM","ID_NAME":"Management","TASK_ID":"MM01","TASK_NAME":"Management 1"}
{"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC02","TASK_NAME":"Human service 2"}
{"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC03","TASK_NAME":"Human service 3"}
{"ID":"QC","ID_NAME":"Quality Control","TASK_ID":"QC01","TASK_NAME":"Quality Control 1"}
{"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC04","TASK_NAME":"Human service 4"}
```

and i would like to group json object which has same id, id_name. For example like this

```
{"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","items": [
     {"TASK_ID":"HC01","TASK_NAME":"Human service 1"},
     {"TASK_ID":"HC02","TASK_NAME":"Human service 2"},
     {"TASK_ID":"HC03","TASK_NAME":"Human service 3"},
     {"TASK_ID":"HC04","TASK_NAME":"Human service 4"}
   ]
},
{"ID":"MM","ID_NAME":"Management","items": [
     {"TASK_ID":"MM01","TASK_NAME":"Managemen 1"}
   ]
},
{"ID":"QC","ID_NAME":"Quality Control","items": [
     {"TASK_ID":"QC01","TASK_NAME":"Quality Control 1"}
   ]
},
```

please help me with my study.

Comment: Decode your json string to an array, use a loop to group, encode the result array to json, in which step you have problem?

Comment: i have step when gruping the array. so i have $task[TASK_ID":"HC01","TASK_NAME":"Human service 1"]. so i add to array $menu["ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","items":$task] and i confused how to put that task array to correct group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We decode the JSON, loop through the objects, add unique `ID`s to a new array, create a placeholder array for `ITEMS`, and append the `TASK` to this `ITEMS`.  After this is all done, we can re-encode the data and return.

**Code:**

```
// Your JSON array of objects
$json = <<<JSON
[
  {"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC01","TASK_NAME":"Human service 1"},
  {"ID":"MM","ID_NAME":"Management","TASK_ID":"MM01","TASK_NAME":"Management 1"},
  {"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC02","TASK_NAME":"Human service 2"},
  {"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC03","TASK_NAME":"Human service 3"},
  {"ID":"QC","ID_NAME":"Quality Control","TASK_ID":"QC01","TASK_NAME":"Quality Control     1"},
  {"ID":"HC","ID_NAME":"Human Capital","TASK_ID":"HC04","TASK_NAME":"Human service 4"}
]
JSON;

// Decode your JSON and create a placeholder array
$objects = json_decode($json);
$grouped = array();

// Loop JSON objects
foreach($objects as $object) {
    if(!array_key_exists($object->ID, $grouped)) { // a new ID...
         $newObject = new stdClass();
    
         // Copy the ID/ID_NAME, and create an ITEMS placeholder
         $newObject->ID = $object->ID;
         $newObject->ID_NAME = $object->ID_NAME;
         $newObject->ITEMS = array();
         
         // Save this new object
         $grouped[$object->ID] = $newObject;
    }
    
    $taskObject = new stdClass();
    
    // Copy the TASK/TASK_NAME
    $taskObject->TASK_ID = $object->TASK_ID;
    $taskObject->TASK_NAME = $object->TASK_NAME;

    // Append this new task to the ITEMS array
    $grouped[$object->ID]->ITEMS[] = $taskObject;
}

// We use array_values() to remove the keys used to identify similar objects
// And then re-encode this data :)
$grouped = array_values($grouped);
$json = json_encode($grouped);
```

**Output:**

[image: Example output]

**Documentation:**

- [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [`stdClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)
- [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists)
- [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)